# How to duplicate a blog on Blogger?

Tags: blogger, export, import

I am wondering how to duplicate a blog. I would like to copy the contents of my original blog and house it under a new URL. The two blogs would not be linked to one another and would be able to grow separately with new posts. Basically I want to have the same blog with same existing posts under two different URLs.

How can this be done?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this isn't ideal from an SEO perspective. Even if all the new content is unique on each site going forward you still have (potentially) loads of existing pages that will be duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

See this: **[Blogger Help: Import and export blogs](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97416)**

To make a copy of your blog's posts and comments, you have to export your blog and then import it to another existing blog.

> ### Export Your blog
>
> To export your blog, simply click "Export Blog" from the **Settings |
>   Other** tab.
>
> Then, click the **Export Blog** button. Your blog will be stored as a
>   Blogger export file (.xml) file which can be kept as a backup on your
>   hard drive or imported into another blog. Exported blogs are not
>   deleted from your dashboard or from Blogger.com.
>
> ### Import Into an Existing Blog
>
> To import posts and comments into an already existing blog, go to
>   **Settings | Other** and click on "Import blog" from the "Blog tools" section. Don't worry -- your template won't be affected by imported
>   content. Next, choose a Blogger export file (.xml) from your hard
>   drive and fill out the word verification beneath. By default, all of
>   your imported posts will remain unpublished until you publish them
>   from your dashboard later. However, if you would rather have all posts
>   published immediately, make sure to check the box next to
>   **Automatically publish all imported posts** before you click **Import Blog**.
>
> If you didn't choose to have your posts publish automatically, you'll
>   need to manually publish them from the **Posts | Imported** tab before
>   they will appear on the web. You can either publish all the posts at
>   once by clicking the checkbox at the top and selecting all before
>   clicking Publish, or simply checking the ones you want to **publish**
>   one by one.
>
> *Imports and exports are only for posts and comments. If you want to save a copy of your template, click the Backup/Restore button on the Template tab.*

Comment: Please summarise any page you link to in the answer. If the link goes dark then this answer will become worse than useless.

Comment: Note that the export / import process:   1)  Will bring through any comments that are made on the original posts (though sometimes there is a delay between importing the posts and the imported comments being visible).   2)  Will keep the original post-date: if you don't want this, them don't automatically publish the imported posts, so that you can publish them later.

Comment: This is very helpful but I'm afraid I don't have an "other" option under my settings.

Comment: What about the images I have in the posts would they also get backed up or more importantly imported to the new blog?